# Loading external urdf with CMakeList for apt installed drake

Tags: drake

I am trying to integrate drake as a physics simulator with in my code. My code does have ros2 as IPC, but the code itself is ROS agnostic. I am using colcon to build the code and I am using CMakeList with drake installed using apt on ubuntu 22.04.

I am trying to load the urdf in drake with in my class structure. I my header file, I defined the following parameters:

```
drake::systems::DiagramBuilder<double> builder_;
drake::multibody::MultibodyPlant<double>* plant_{};
drake::geometry::SceneGraph<double>* scene_graph_{};`
```

In my source file, my code is

```
std::tie(plant_, scene_graph_) = AddMultibodyPlantSceneGraph(&builder_, std::make_unique<MultibodyPlant<double>>(1e-3));

const std::string urdf = drake::FindResourceOrThrow("path_to_urdf/urdf.urdf");
    
drake::multibody::Parser(plant_).AddModelFromFile(urdf);
```

However, when I run the code, I get the following message

```
[****] terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::runtime_error'
[***]   what():  Drake resource_path '~/path_to_urdf/urdf.urdf' does not start with drake/.
```

I verified that file is available on the link. I tried creating the manual drake folder as well, but it keeps complaining.

I did saw the issue https://github.com/RobotLocomotion/drake-external-examples/issues/170 open but I am not sure if it is related to that. Any help or guidance will be highly appreciated.

Comment: I was able to resolve this problem by copying the urdf in /opt/drake/share/drake/ and then defining the path from drake/path_to_urdf/urdf.urdf. This solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

In general, don't use `FindResourceOrThrow` to load models.  [It's intended only for Drake build system resources](https://github.com/RobotLocomotion/drake/pull/18692).

To use `AddModelFromFile`, just pass it an absolute path:

```cpp
std::tie(plant_, scene_graph_) = ...
drake::multibody::Parser(plant_).AddModels("/full/path/to/myproject/urdf/foo.urdf");
```

You can also use ROS package paths, if you are using `package.xml` files:

```cpp
std::tie(plant_, scene_graph_) = ...
drake::multibody::Parser parser(plant_);
parser.package_map().PopulateFromRosPackagePath();
std::string package_dir = parser.package_map().GetPath("myproject");
parser.AddModels(package_dir + "/urdf/foo.urdf");
```

In the next version of Drake (v1.13.0), there will also be a `AddModelsFromUrl` function to make ROS package paths even easier.